# Do I have to get a signed URL for every image on AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signed-url

Lets say I have a social media app like Instagram. Do I have to get a signed URL for every single image?
Each user sees like 100 images, does that mean that it has to get 100 singed URLs for each user?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: What is your use-case? Are these images public, or are they meant to be kept private except for authorised users?

Comment: They are public. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: If the images are public, then you do not need to use pre-signed URLs. You can just point to them directly. "Public" means accessible to anyone without needing to authenticate.

Comment: How do I specify it as public? Even when I have ACL:'public-read' , it says unauthorized. @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an entire Amazon S3 bucket "public" (or a path within the bucket), use a **bucket policy**.

From [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html):

> The following example policy grants the `s3:GetObject` permission to any public anonymous users. This permission allows anyone to read the object data, which is useful for when you configure your bucket as a website and want everyone to be able to read objects in the bucket.

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before you use a bucket policy to grant read-only permission to an anonymous user, you must **disable Block Public Access settings for your bucket**.